# error while uploading image android to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an error while uploading an image from my Android app to MySQL server.

I have followed a tutorial, but could't achieve to do this task.
Am using InnoDB table with 4 columns(id , firstname ,lastname , image).
so when i run my app and start typing to my edittext, than click save , it works and data stored into database.
my point is: how to upload an image into database using my code.?

**Signature.java**

```
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    File directory = Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    File file = new File(directory, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".JPEG");
                    FileOutputStream out = null;
                    Bitmap bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();

                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytedata = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytedata);
                            byte[] data = bytedata.toByteArray();
                            String imagedata = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String name="prescription";


                        } else {
                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    parameters.put("firstname", txt1.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("lastname", txt2.getText().toString());
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('user', 'root');
define('password', '');
define('databaseName', 'tutorial'); 
$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);
mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connection.php';
    createStudent();
}
function createStudent()
{
    global $connect;
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];   
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $query = " Insert into students(firstname,lastname) values ('$firstname','$lastname');";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not following, `it works and data stored into database` so it works? You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: yah the texts on the edittext uploaded successful, but image is not uploading into database. @user3783243

Comment: You only write `firstname` and `lastname` to the DB. I'm also not sure if you are sending the image correctly from the JAVA.

Comment: @user3783243 yah i know , but how can i modify existing code for uploading an image in insert.php file.?

Comment: Is the image being sent as a `$_FILE` from the JAVA? Update the query and store the image, or its location on the filesystem.

Comment: @user3783243            File directory = Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                        File file = new File(directory, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".JPEG");
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        Bitmap bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();

Comment: @user3783243 the code for uploading already in the post.

Comment: Yes, I saw I don't know JAVA though. The PHP/mysql brought me here. If that is submitting as a file then access it as such on the PHP side. Currently your PHP does nothing with a file.

Comment: @user3783243 so as am dding firstname , lastname in insert.php i should add one for and image am i right?     but how to add one for image becoz i didnt upload in image before to a server , i just know about the strings type.